# How can I convert a MVC sql query to a Linq query?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new in MVC. Linq is the system of making queries in database. but I am having difficulties right now with Linq. Anyone know how to convert my sql statement to Linq?

My entities, seperate context

localDB.summaries

accountDB.account

---

```
SELECT * FROM summary 
WHERE studentID = 
(SELECT studentID FROM accounts WHERE username = 'username123')
```

---

```
FROM user IN localDB.summaries
WHERE -------- please guide my linq--------
SELECT user
```

Comment: Also, you can use the linq lambda expression too: `localDB.summaries.Where(x => localDB.accounts.Any(y => y.studentID == x.studentID && y.username == "username123"));`

Answer (score 1):

At a guess without knowing your entities:

```
var query = from user in localDB.summaries
join account in localDB.accounts on user.studentID equals account.studentID
where account.username == "username123"
select user;
```

Comment: it is different context. localDB for summaries and accountDB for username

im having error: 

System.NotSupportedException: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

Comment: You never specified that in your question

Comment: im so sorry about that sir. i edited now the details and added it.

Comment: Your sql implied that the tables are in the same database?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that accounts table has been mapped with student on the basis of student id I mean there is a foreign key relationship so by assuming that:

```
var data = localDB.summaries.where(c=>c.Students.Account.FirstorDefault().username == "username123")
```

Comment: i added some information in my problem. i have to context. localDB for summaries and accountDB for accounts.